# How do I create flint and steel that only is usable on obsidian?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have seen this done in many other adventure maps. Does anyone have any ideas? I need a flint and steel that can only be used on obsidian.

Answer (score 6):

The player will need to be in adventure mode (`/gamemode adventure @a`). Then, you can control what blocks the flint and steel can be used on with the `CanPlaceOn` list.

**1.12-:**

```
/give @a flint_and_steel 1 0 {CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:obsidian"]}
```

**1.13+:**

```
/give @a flint_and_steel{CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:obsidian"]}
```